# Extracting data from txt files to import in a mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

In a directory i have a lot of .txt files containing some common data, such as:

```
name: XXX
surname: YYY
age: ZZZ
```

My problem is to read, for each txt file, these infos and to populate a mysql database for each correspondent field: name, surname, age.
As txt files are very huge i need to handle only the header of each file (the first 15 lines) where are stored the infos i need. However in the headers the infos i need are not formatted in the same way, so i think that using regular expressions might be the best choice.
Could someone help me?

The following lines are the code i'm using right now. How and where i could modify the code to reach my goal?

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $row = explode(":", $line);
    $query = "INSERT INTO tablename SET val1 = '" . trim($row[0]) . "', val2 = '" . trim($row[1]) . "'";
    mysql_query($query);
}

?>
```

Comment: Which code do you already have?

Comment: Where do you need help? You have a job consisting of a lot of smaller issues: try to break it up, try come up with a solution for them, and if something specific does not work, come back with a question about that. As it stands, this question is to broad to be answered in a useful form for this site.

Comment: Why negative points to my question?

Comment: because you should post some code... (I haven't down voted) and I'm actually working on your answer.

Comment: You are receiving down votes because this is not a "write me some code" site.  If you have code you are having trouble with, this is the place.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see what kind of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, excuse me for this. I can edit my question and insert a code. So I hope will be deleted my negative rates.

Answer (score 2):

**This is what you need:**

```
<?php
    //create a mysqli connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


//Get all the files inside a directory
    $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/to/txt/folder");
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($iterator as $file) {

      $content = file_get_contents($file);

      for ($x=0; $x<15; $x++)
       {

        preg_match_all('/name:(.*?)\s+surname:(.*?)\s+age:([0-9]+)/sim', $content, $results, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        $name = $results[1][$x];
        $surname = $results[2][$x];
        $age = $results[3][$x];

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (name, surname, age)
VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$age')");

}

    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**NOTES:**
The above code works with PHP 5
The regex isn't bullet proof, you may need to tweak it a bit to fit your needs.
Make sure you create a database with the fields that match the INSERT query...

Comment: Hi Tuga, thanks very much for your code i think this will help me very much, expecially the preg_match_all part.
As files to handle are very large, is there a way to focus the preg-match check only for the first 15 lines of each file?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Based on you comment, I've updated the answer to match only the first 15 records.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it is not practical to write a batch job in PHP.  However, in your post you mention you would like to use the crontab, so I presume you are on some flavor of Linux, in which case you can use Bash.

Create a script: `/home/yourid/bin/processdata.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# set-up some variables
outstanding="/some/dir/outstanding"
processed="/some/dir/processed"
tempfile="/tmp/$$.sql"

# set a trap to delete our ${tempfile} on exit or ctrl+c
trap "rm -f ${tempfile}" EXIT INT

# list each .txt file in the outstanding directory
ls -1 ${outstanding}/*.txt | while read filename
do

    # stash the data after the ":" into a bash variable
    name=$(awk -F":" '/^name/ { print $2 }' ${outstanding}/${filename})
    surname=$(awk -F":" '/^surname/ { print $2 }' ${outstanding}/${filename})
    age=$(awk -F":" '/^age/ { print $2 }' ${outstanding}/${filename})

    # echo a mysql command into our ${tempfile}
    echo "INSERT INTO some_table (name,surname,age) VALUES(\"${name}\",\"${surname}\",\"${age}\")" > ${tempfile}

    # run a mysql command using these variables
    mysql --user=username --password=password db_name < ${tempfile} || {

        # if there is a problem, shout about it
        echo "Error while processing file: ${outstanding}/${filename}"

        # break the loop (to leave the file in ${outstanding}
        break

    }

    # move the file out of the way
    mv ${outstanding}/${filename} ${processed}/

done
```

Then add a crontab entry to run it every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/yourid/bin/processdata.sh >> /home/yourid/logs/processdata.log 2>&1
```

Some things to note:

- The script does very little error handling.
- SQL is executed from a file which is a security risk (albeit somewhat negated by using $$).
- The directories used must exist for this to work.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be done with something like this.

```
<?php

$INPUT_DIR="inputdir";
$OUTPUT_DIR="processed";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

function process_file($fileIn) {

        // Read the content
        $content=file($fileIn); // If they are small

        $data=array();
        foreach($content as $line) {
                $explosion = explode(":", $line); // Use this to parse the file. Doesn't work with : inside the value
                $key=strtolower($explosion[0]); // before :
                $value=ltrim($explosion[1]); // after :, remove initial space
                $data[$key]=$value;
        }

        // Write the content
        if (empty($data["name"] || empty($data["surname"] || empty($data["age"]) {
                error_log("Incomplete fields file found at ". $fileIn);
                return false;
        }

        $myquery = "INSERT into ages (name,surname,age) values (:name, :surname, :age)";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        return $sth->execute(array(':name' => $data["name"], ':surname' => $data["surname"], ':age' => $data["age"]));
}
// Create output dir if not exists
if(!is_dir($OUTPUT_DIR)) {
        mkdir($OUTPUT_DIR)
}

// Get list of files in INPUT_DIR
$files_to_process = glob($INPUT_DIR."/*");
foreach($files_to_process as $fileIn) {
        echo basename($fileIn). "\n";
        if(process_file($fileIn)) {
                rename($fileIn, $OUTPUT_DIR."/".basename($fileIn));
        }
}


?>
```

Indeed I think you can use an integration engine like [Mirth Connect](http://www.mirthcorp.com/products/mirth-connect)  to have an file input and a SQL output. It may be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example to get your started:

```
$text = <<<TXT
name: XXX
surname: YYY
age: ZZZ
TXT;

$final = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
    list($key, $data) = explode(': ', $line);
    $final[$key] = $data;
}

print_r($final);
// Array ( [name] => XXX [surname] => YYY [age] => ZZZ )
```